# Bash aliases don't work when defined in separate file called by .bashrc

Tags: bash

My bash aliases are defined in a file `.bash_aliases` that is called from `.bashrc`. I know the file is properly executed because I put an `echo` command at the end of `.bash_aliases`.
However, aliases only work when defined in `.bashrc`, not when defined in `.bash_aliases`.

`alias -p` does not have any output.

in `.bashrc`:

```
~/.bash_aliases
```

`.bash_aliases`:

```
#!/bin/bash

#All bash aliases

alias a="a.sh"
alias b="b.sh"

echo "All aliases configured"
```

Comment: if [ -f $HOME/.bash_aliases ]; then
        source $HOME/.bash_aliases
fi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They don't work because you run `~/.bash_aliases` as a separate process. The aliases are created in that new process then it ends. The current shell is not affected.

In order to make them work you have to run `~/.bash_aliases` inside the current shell.

It is easy. Use the `source` shell command:

Change **`.bashrc`** to read:

```
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

**Remark:** you may also use `. ~/.bash_aliases` instead.
It is the same command as `source`, just shorter. I prefer to use `source` in scripts because it is more visible. This short form is preferable (because it is shorter) when you need to run a script inside the current shell from the command line.